# No of Strings that can be formed by putting spaces in between by Recurssion

Tags: string, recursion

This code prints all posibble strings two times it would be very helpful if someone corrects it.

```
static void possStr(String S, int i) {
    if(i>=S.length()) {
        return;
    }
    
    String C = S.substring(0, i+1) + " " + S.substring(i+1, S.length());
    
    System.out.println(C);
    
    possStr(C, i+2);
    possStr(S, i+1);
}
```

Comment: Can you give us what kind of results you expect ?

Comment: like input is string abc and output will be abc ,a bc, ab c, a b c.

Comment: You are close to a solution. You should try with smaller strings like "", "a" and "ab". ```S.length()``` is not needed as second parameters of substring